# DB browser for sqlite does not work

Tags: python, sql

I write a python code to create a table,but when I open DB browser for SQLite, it does not the table I have created, I am new to database, so can anyone tell me what is wrong with it ? Many thanks!

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test1.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test''')

cur.execute('''
CREATE TABLE Test (azaz TEXT, count INTEGER)''')

cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Test (azaz, count)
        VALUES ( 'aa', 1 )''' )
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

[image link:imgur.com/epfar.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyL0t.png)

Comment: From the image it might look like you are clicking on "new database" instead of "open database".

Comment: @wind85 Thank you very much !! It seems that I am not very familiar with DB for sqlite, thank you for finding my real problem !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right and if you try:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('test1.sqlite') 
row = conn.execute('SELECT * FROM Test').fetchone() 
print("azaz=", row[0]) 
print("count=", row[1])
```

You will see this output:

```
('azaz=', u'aa')
('count=', 1)
```

So the table has been created and values has been inserted in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested your code and it works flawlessly. I have used python-3.5 and DB Broswer for sqlite, tested on window 7 pro.